# Why Google Analytics "minute" dimension doesn't work?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I try to execute the following request usign Google Reporting API:

```
 "reportRequests": [
    {
        "metrics": [
            {
                "expression": "ga:sessions"
            }
        ],
        "dimensions": [
            {
                "name": "ga:date"
            },
            {
                "name": "ga:minute"
            }
        ],
        "dateRanges": [
            {
                "startDate": "2018-01-02",
                "endDate": "2018-04-17"
            }
        ],
        "viewId": "validViewId",
        "hideValueRanges": true,
        "hideTotals": true
    }
]
```

Unfortunately I get no data. But when I use only `"date"` dimension, without `"minute"`, I get some data in response.

Could someone please explain such a weird behavior?

Comment: Not all of the dimensions have data for them If the data doesn't exist then you are not going to be able to get any analytics back on it.  try using ga:dateHourMinute.

Comment: I tried to use "dateHourMinute" dimension, but no result. To be precize, every date earlier then 2018-08-08 if to use "minute" dimension, results in no data.

Answer (score 0):

As you are querying historical data (here > 2 years) the level of granularity of your data would be impacted by the retention period defined on property level. Meaning that beyond the retention period you can only query a combination of dimensions that are covered by Google Analytics **standard aggregated tables** ([GA Help Center](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7667196?hl=en))

In your case the combination "Session | Date | Minute" is not part of Google Analytics aggregated tables, however "Session | Date" is.

You can recreate this phenomenon by using your query on different time ranges: within the retention period vs. outside the retention period.

Comment: Does that mean that on another account I will get some data with such dimension-metric combination?

Comment: It still depends on the defined retention period of the GA property in question. The default retention period of a GA web property is 26 month. However if you edited the retention period back then when this feature was introduced to value of "38", "50 "months or even "no expiry" you could access the data of this specific dimension-metric combination for a longer time in this specific property. I hope this clarifies your question.